# Jquery UI Autocomplete from multiple data sources using UNION query

Tags: php, jquery, sql, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

The following query works properly to pull company names from one table into jquery UI autocomplete:

```
SELECT name FROM company WHERE name LIKE "'. mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['term']) .'%"
```

The result is looped into an array and encoded to JSON then returned to jquery and displays autocomplete suggestions properly.

I am trying to modify it to pull from two or more tables:

```
SELECT name
FROM (
SELECT name
FROM company
UNION ALL SELECT CONCAT( fname,  ' ', lname ) 
FROM contact
) AS name
WHERE name LIKE  "'. mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['term']) .'%"
```

The goal in this case would be to have the autocomplete list include company names and contact names. When I run the query independently of my application (just using PhpMyAdmin console) with a sample search term, it successfully displays the desired results. However in the context of my jquery ui autocomplete form, it does not return any autocomplete suggestions.

I would appreciate any suggestions. Thanks!

**EDIT: Sample SQL results**

Here is the result I get when I run each of these queries in PhpMyAdmin with test query "mi".

*My original one-table source query:*

```
Generation Time: Jul 20, 2011 at 01:40 AM
Generated by: phpMyAdmin 3.3.9 / MySQL 5.5.8
SQL query: SELECT name FROM company WHERE name LIKE "mi%" LIMIT 0, 30 ; 
Rows: 6

name
[rows removed]
```

*Mr. Wanda's suggested modification:*

```
Generation Time: Jul 20, 2011 at 01:50 AM
Generated by: phpMyAdmin 3.3.9 / MySQL 5.5.8
SQL query: SELECT temptable.name FROM ( SELECT name as name FROM company UNION ALL SELECT CONCAT( fname, ' ', lname ) as name FROM contact ) AS temptable WHERE temptable.name LIKE "mi%" ; 
Rows: 15

name
[rows removed]
```

Both are valid SQL that result in a table of one column with rows containing names, but only the first one works in jquery ui. =(

Comment: I'm sort of following, although I don't know how your UI autocomplete form works or what it expects.  How many columns do you get in the result set when you union the tables?  How many columns does your UI expect?

Comment: Ah sorry, was just trying to keep it simple. Both queries above are resulting in one column called "name". The jquery is expecting an array with a label and a value, both of which I am assigning the "name" array to. Not sure if this is the best practice, but I got it from an example I found online and it worked fine for the simpler query. Here is the relevant php:

Comment: while( $row = mysql_fetch_array([THE SQL QUERY], MYSQL_ASSOC) )
 {
  $data[] = array(
   'label' => $row['name'] ,
   'value' => $row['name']
  );
 }

Comment: @jmiller: Do you get any javascript errors? Have you opened firebug to see the differences in the data being retrieved via AJAX?

Comment: Andrew - no javascript errors with either query. The first (simpler) query works, the second one just does not produce any autocomplete suggestions, although it does not show any errors. The autocomplete source in the jquery code is another php file with code to make the SQL query and then return the JSON encoded array.. so I don't think in production it could show an error. I will try the firebug suggestion tomorrow. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**See bold text below.**

SELECT **temptable.[name]**
FROM (

SELECT name **as [name]**
  FROM company

UNION ALL

SELECT **TRIM(ISNULL(fname,'') + ' ' + ISNULL(lname,'')) as [name]**
  FROM contact

) AS **temptable**
WHERE 
**temptable.name** LIKE  "'. mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['term']) .'%"

Comment: Thanks for your help... tried this change but still no luck. I posted the results of running these SQL queries independently of jquery above in my original post.

Comment: why is there a LIMIT clause on the first one?  Also, if you run the contact query independently, how many rows do you get in the result set?

Comment: Oops, PhpMyAdmin added the LIMIT automatically.. it does not go in my application, but the results are the same anyways.. the contact query independently is resulting in 9 rows, although for some reason it says "Showing rows 0 - 8 (9 total)"

Comment: and the contact query (running independently) shows perfectly in the jquery ui?

Comment: Ah.. no! It does not... interestingly, I tried just the "fname AS name" without the CONCAT and it did work (still independent from the first query)... I wonder if the CONCAT is causing jquery a problem...

Comment: i wonder if you have a null fname or null lname.  Is there an ISNULL function in MYSQL?  I only use SQL Server at work.  Try RTRIM(LTRIM(ISNULL(fname, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(lname,''))) .. you will have to find the equivalent in mysql

Comment: Just took a quick glance at the table, it's only a couple hundred lines but there are a few null values (some of the data was imported from a previous source before we had validation). Could that possibly be causing the issue? It's interesting that the raw query outputs fine (even with the CONCAT), it's only jquery that seems to be having a problem. I'll have to see if I can clean up the data tomorrow and try it out. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Got this error with the modified code: "#1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ISNULL'"... I'll play around with it a little bit to see how I can translate it to MySQL.

Comment: I don't know enough about MySQL.  My recommendation is to keep it really simple, and look at the MySQL ISNULL documentation online.  Try doing a very simple query using that function.  All it's doing is it returns the second argument's value (which is '') if the first argument (the name) is null.

Comment: Well in searching for ISNULL documentation I found coalesce, and replaced your ISNULL line with this: "SELECT COALESCE(CONCAT(fname, " ", lname), fname, lname) as name". Which is now returning the concatenated string of fname and lname, OR if one of those values is null, then just the fname, or just the lname. THANKS again for all your help!